# How can I read headers on an html page served over https using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I read my website headers when it is served over https? I tried

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

But this does not work for https pages.

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. It should tell you why you can't access the data.

Comment: … having just run that code on an HTTPS site, it works perfect. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: you mean this code should work for https pages as well?

Comment: It **does** work for HTTPS pages when I test it.

Comment: I am getting ` Failed to load resource https://localhost:9000/dashboard?scope=openid&code=W8o853olWPA15zyhcIh5shayCovHfw ` Do you think its because of the query parameters? Because my application route is defined for "/dashboard" only

Comment: You're loading `document.location`. That's the URL of the page you are looking at. If the URL works when you load it normally, and doesn't work when you load the same URL with XHR, then it isn't going to be because of the query string.